# Normal distribution and t-distribution, confidence intervals

Tags: statistics, normal-distribution

In many cases, the $σ$ of a normal distribution is not known. So looking for an interval x<sub>n</sub> +- (z<sub>α/2</sub>)$\dfrac{σ}{\sqrt{n}
}$ without knowing the σ leads to a similar expression with σ=S<sub>n</sub> .
Since S<sub>n</sub> depends on the sample size, we no longer have a normal distribution. It is said that we have a $t$-distribution. What exactly this means, also how could we interpret the degrees of freedom, and eventually why it converges to a normal distribution ? ( as the degrees of freedom increase )

Comment: Suppose you have a random sample of size $n$ from a normal population with unknown mean $\nu$ and variance $\sigma^2$.  Then a 95% CI for$\mu$ is of the form $\bar X \pm t^*S/\sqrt{n},$ where $\bar X$ is the sample mean, $S^2$ is the sample variance, and $t^*$ cuts 2.5% of the probability from the upper tail of Student's t distribution with $n-1$ degrees of freedom. // Values of $t^*$ are given in printed tables and can be obtained from statistical software. For example, if $n = 20,$ then R statistical software gives $t^* = 2.093,$ as follows:`qt(.975, 19)` returns 2.093024.

Comment: Please see https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference for formatting your posts properly. Use `\sigma` for $\sigma$, `\alpha` for $\alpha$, etc.

Comment: Peter, I see you're relative new to MSE. If you feel that an answer solved the problem, please mark it as 'accepted' by clicking the green check mark $\left( \color{limegreen}{\checkmark}\right)$. This helps us to keep the focus on (older) question which has no good answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Comment** continued with Example.

In R statistical software, the procedure `t.test` provides a 95% confidence interval for $\mu$ as part of the output.

Suppose we have a sample of size $n = 20$ from a normal population:

```
x = rnorm(20, 100, 15)
summary(x); length(x);  sd(x)
   Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
  79.91   86.73  100.52  101.92  109.29  140.36 
[1] 20           # sample size
[1] 17.97414     # sample standard deviation

t.test(x)$conf.int
[1]  93.50513 110.32944 
attr(,"conf.level")
[1] 0.95
```

You can use the formula in my Comment along with the value of $t^*$ given there and $\bar X = 101.92$ and $S = 17.97$ to verify this confidence interval
$(93.505, 110.329).$

*Notes:* (a) Here is the sample used in the example--rounded to 3 places and sorted from smallest to largest:

```
sort(round(x,3))    
 [1]  79.910  80.391  82.185  82.339  86.338  86.867  92.912  93.487  94.925  99.789
[11] 101.253 104.700 107.627 107.857 108.890 110.477 111.960 129.211 136.867 140.360
```

(b) Here is the same confidence interval from Minitab statistical software:

```
One-Sample T 

 N    Mean  StDev  SE Mean       95% CI
20  101.92  17.97     4.02  (93.51, 110.33)
```